xtest fails on IMX8MPLUS
On the imx8MPLUS-BB development board, install optee, run xtest on it, and the following error occurs below.
enter image description here
Later on, I modified r = ADBG_EXPECT_TEEC_RESULT(c, TEEC_ERROR_SECURITY, res) into r = ADBG_EXPECT_TEEC_RESULT(c, TEEC_ERROR_GENERIC, res), and then found the following problem again.
enter image description here
enter image description here
Very confused, don't know how to solve it
Best Regards!
